# Ubuntu. VGA to USB driver

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, vga

I'm having trouble finding information about this. I know there are similar questions, but the only one with an answer is 5 years old and the answer is outdated.

I just bought a new laptop, they don't come with VGA inputs anymore (at least the newest ones). So, in order to use my external monitor I bought a VGA - USB adapter ([J5Create JUA210 USB Display Adapter](http://www.j5create.com/our-products/external-video-adapters/jua210.html)). I'm in desperate need of making it work with KDE-Ubuntu. Does anyone know where can I find drivers that could help me to solve this situation?

If I do `sudo lsusb`, I can see linux recognizes the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:036c Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0711:5200 Magic Control Technology Corp. <--- this one
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c018 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Give us the result of lsusb please. What happens, after connecting? What exactly is not working? No output?

Comment: @davidbaumann, just included lsusb output. And yes, I have no output in the external monitor, it remains black as if it was not connected.

Comment: @alejoss did you open up the 'Display settings" and hit "Detect" to try and detect the extra output port and use it?

Comment: @ThomasW. Can't find the "detect" option. Im using KDE, sorry for not saying that before.

Comment: @ThomasW. Anyway, logged into Gnome, found the "detect" button, clicked it and nothing ... any other ideas :/?

Comment: What's the brand of your USB-to-VGA adapter?

Comment: @Perumal93 follow the link. Its a JSCreate

Answer (score 3):

Having done a lot of research into these devices, I had a pretty good idea what I'd find if I looked into this one.  The manufacturer of this product openly supports LINUX for other devices they sell, but not for this one.  In other words, it is extremely unlikely this device will ever be supported for linux.  If you do as much research as I have, you will also learn that fewer than 1 in 20 such devices are linux compatible, and those that are can be quite expensive.

My advice to you is that unless your VGA monitor is extremely large or valuable, that  you purchase a new monitor with an HDMI input, as it is very likely that unless your laptop is in fact a tiny little netbook or something, it actually does have an HDMI output port on it.  In case you don't know what HDMI looks like, it looks very much like a USB port.

If you would do us the courtesy of giving us the model number of your laptop, I'm sure one of us can find the time to determine the actually connectivity of your laptop, such as whether it has HDMI or perhaps some other sort of video connector such as "displayport".

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can ask support to share driver sources ... it is obviously old matters and j5Create will have the chance to go for such help. Then a community will be able to add some new (really old) drivers to the workarounds.